# C# Project Build Failure in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have MSBuild configured on a Jenkins instance to build the C# projects. the projects without any namespace in the project name, builds successfully whereas any project with a space in its name like "abc def.csproj" doesn't build. I get the following error:

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.

I have MSBuild plugin v1.26 installed for Jenkins.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: can you somehow pass the project names surrounded with quotes like `"abc def.csproj"`?

Comment: That is what I thought initially. I do pass the end state names like this. However, Jenkins picks up the project name based on the SVN path that we provide in the job configuration.